# JavaFX - How do I properly use binding to keep the root node centered in the Stage

Tags: javafx, binding, scrollpane

JavaFX newbie here.

My primary question is:
1) How do I properly use binding to keep the root node centered in the Stage
I attempted to do so in my code but I have it commented out near the bottom of the start() method.  There may be an easier way to accomplish centering my VBox pane on the Stage (even when the stage is horizontally scaled), and I'm open to hearing those.  But ultimately I'm trying to learn how binding works and how these DoubleProperties and ObservableValues work.  Where can I go to learn more about binding and how these properties work?

2) Just for kicks, if there's an easier way to center the VBox, that would be helpful to know, of course.

3) As a temporary solution, I attempted to restrict the scaling of the stage beyond a maximum size with maxHeight and maxWidth (also commented out near the bottom of start() method).  However, when I did this, the scrollPane ceased to scroll all the way to the bottom of the textArea!  (click submit button to see dummy data)

Thanks in advance!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class BindingTest extends Application{

   //create TextFields and TextArea with greater scope for reference in EventHandler
   private TextField tfLoanAmt = new TextField();
   private TextField tfNumYears = new TextField(); 
   private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

   public void start(Stage primaryStage){
      tfLoanAmt.setPrefColumnCount(15);
      tfNumYears.setPrefColumnCount(2);
      //create Labels, Buttons, and add to HBox
      Label lblLoanAmt = new Label("Loan Amount");
      Label lblNumYears = new Label("Number of Years");
      Button btShowTable = new Button("Show Table");
      //instantiate and register action handler       
      ShowTableClass showTableHandler = new ShowTableClass();
      btShowTable.setOnAction(showTableHandler);
      HBox hBox = new HBox(4);
      hBox.getChildren().addAll(lblLoanAmt, tfLoanAmt, lblNumYears, tfNumYears, btShowTable);
      //add textArea to ScrollPane
      ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent"); //hide super annoying gray border that adds nothing but trouble
      //create VBox to hold HBox and ScrollPane, and add them to VBox
      VBox vBox = new VBox(4);
      vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
      vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox, scrollPane);
      //create scene and add to stage
      Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 500, 250);
      primaryStage.setTitle("Loan Comparison");
      //primaryStage.setMaxWidth(510); 
      //primaryStage.setMaxHeight(260); //adding either of these disrupts scrolling in scrollPane??? 
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      //vBox.layoutXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(vBox.prefWidthProperty().divide(2)));
      //vBox.layoutYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(vBox.prefHeightProperty().divide(2)));      

      primaryStage.centerOnScreen(); // does not seem to be centering it perfectly on screen
      primaryStage.show();
   } // end start()


   class ShowTableClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{   
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent e){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.format("Dummy Data\n"));
         for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
            sb.append(String.format("--------Line %d--------\n", x));
         textArea.setText(sb.toString());
      } // end handle()
   } // end class ShowTableClass



   public static void main(String[] args){
      Application.launch(args);
   } // end main()



} // end class BindingTest
```

Comment: The root node will be sized to fill the scene: there is no additional space around it in order to center it in the scene. (Set a background color on the vbox to see this.) Sort of related: not sure why you are putting the text area in a scroll pane: a text area carries its own scroll bars.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm using a scrollPane either, I read somewhere it's better to use it than the textArea's scrollbars? But I'd still like to know why it fails to scroll down when I set maxHeight for Stage.

Comment: When I scale the scene vertically, everything stays centered due to the vBox.setAlignment().  However, it does not position itself when the stage is scaled horizontally.  So I'd like to know why.  And I'd like to understand property binding.

Comment: Because your Hbox is aligned left (by default). Call `hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);` as well. The scrolling is because when you add the data, the text area gets scroll bars as well as the scroll pane, so you are scrolling the wrong scroll bar. Scroll right and you will see the built-in scrollbars for the text area, which let you scroll... But really, take out the scroll pane. The binding code is correct, it just won't do anything (the root node ignores layout properties). You can read up on properties and bindings [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).

Comment: New Question: I changed the background color to red for vBox.  Now when I scale the stage to the right, I see what appears to be the remnant gray area of what is likely the scrollPane.  What's up with that and how would I remove that in future scenarios?

Comment: By removing the scroll pane...

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, and I'll take your advice regarding scrollPane.  But just so i understand, when I did what you said, everything stayed centered except the scrollPane scaled itself to fit the new stage size.  Any way to fix that too?  Thanks again

Comment: Haha.  Point taken.  Does one ever use scrollPanes then?  And how would I solve the gray box problem then?

Comment: Well, yes, just not for a text area. The gray box is the scroll pane viewport: it's the same background color as most other containers so it won't generally look wrong. (Which is why you don't see it if you don't change the root background color.) To restyle the scroll pane you really need to restyle its viewport, so in an external CSS file: `.scrollpane > .viewport { -fx-background-color: ...; }`. Or, probably better, instead of setting `-fx-background-color` on the root node, set the looked-up-color `-fx-background: red;`: that will apply to all child nodes.

Comment: Awesome. I removed the scrollPane and just used the textArea and the scrolling problem went away when I restricted the maxHeight of the stage.  And just for kicks, I returned to the file with the ScrollPane and fixed all the centering problems with:          scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
scrollPane.setMaxWidth(500);